# Select/DeSelect All doesnt work for single record

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a javascipt as follows:

```
if (document.forms[0].Check_All.value=="Select All") {
    for (i = 0; i < chk.length; i++) {
            chk[i].checked = true;
            document.forms[0].Check_All.value = "DeSelect All";                
    }
} else {
    for (i = 0; i < chk.length; i++) {
        chk[i].checked = false;
        document.forms[0].Check_All.value = "Select All";
    }
}
```

It is used to select and de-select checkboxes. It works fine when `chk.length == 2` and above. However when I have only 1 record `chk.length` is `undefined` and it wouldn't work. Any guess why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because when there’s only on form element with the specified name, you get access to that element directly, whereas with more elements with the same name you get a collection.

You can work around that in simple situations like this with something like

```
if(chk.length == undefined) {
  chk = new Array(chk);
}
```

If it was not a collection before, after that `chk` will be an array – which behaves *similar* to a collection, at least in the way that you can access it’s length property and access its (one) element with a numeric index.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery function to check all checkbox

```
$("input :checkbox").each(function(){
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
});
```